# How to replicate user request using Request::create laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hi guys I just wanted to ask your opinion or ideas on how to do this

i have a url like:

`example.com/urlhere`

handled by:

`SomeController@someFunction(Request $request)`

the `$request` object contains a lot of data including Server Bag Parameter

I want to create the same with exact object `$request` using:

`Request::create('/urlhere')`

any idea how to do it?

Comment: Is this for testing purpose? Or you need to create this kind of request inside your Laravel app?

Comment: @SureshVelusamy I need to create this request inside my laravel app, I want to visit all my pages in the sitemap

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/47a543f5bd0801eed2082f9ecbae0c849ec32a4b/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php#L333. refer `call` Method. 

its has a good definition of achieving your need. I hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create a similar object.

`$request->request->add($array)` you can pass array to create a similar object.

there is also another way to create a single variable in the request like

`$request->request->set('Key',$value)`

Hope this helps.